# Solving $\cos\frac{a+2 x}{\frac{5 a^2}{2}+2ax+2x^2}=\cos\frac{2 x-a}{\frac{5 a^2}{2}-2 a x+2 x^2}$, with $a\geq\frac{1}{2\pi}$

Tags: trigonometry

I mean $$\cos \left(\frac{a+2 x}{\frac{5 a^2}{2}+2 a x+2 x^2}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{2 x-a}{\frac{5 a^2}{2}-2 a x+2 x^2}\right) \wedge a\geq \frac{1}{2 \pi } $$ over the reals which depends on  a real-valued parameter $a$.

I came across it in the Internet, knowing the answer $ \left\{0, \frac {a \sqrt 5} 2, -\frac {a \sqrt 5} 2\right\}$. My Mathematica is running for hours without any output, solving it.

Comment: What is your definition of $\wedge$?

Comment: @JacobCheverie: This is a standard notation for the logical conjunction (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). Thak you for your interest to the question.

Comment: I understand it as AND, I didn't know if you had another definition. I don't understand how you are using a Boolean expression with an inequality.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: In other words, how to solve it over the reals, assuming a real-valued parameter $a\ge \frac 1 {2\pi}$? Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Okay, I read that incorrectly. I am going to make a small edit that will make things a little more clear.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: No edit, please. I am sure the question is quite understable. I  will be waiting for your solution. Good luck!

Comment: Weird, Mathematica should solve it in a snap.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: the OP is right, this is perfectly readable.

Comment: @the downvoter: Can you base your downvote? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 
$$\cos A-\cos B=-2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$$
we get
$$\sin\left(\frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}+\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}\right)=0\tag1$$or$$\sin\left(\frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}-\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}\right)=0\tag2$$

---

First, let us solve $(1)$.

We have
$$(1)\implies \frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}+\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}=k\pi$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Here, let
$$p(x):=\frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}$$
Then, we get
$$p'(x)=\frac{-2(2x-a)(2x+3a)}{(4x^2+4ax+5a^2)^2}$$
from which we have
$$-\frac{1}{4a}=p\left(-\frac 32a\right)\le p(x)\le p\left(\frac a2\right)=\frac{1}{4a}\tag3$$

Also, let $$q(x):=\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}$$
Then, we get$$q'(x)=\frac{-2(2x+a)(2x-3a)}{(5a^2-4ax+4x^2)^2}$$
from which we have
$$-\frac{1}{4a}=q\left(-\frac a2\right)\le q(x)\le q\left(\frac 32a\right)=\frac{1}{4a}\tag4$$

From $(3)(4)$, we get
$$-\pi \le -\frac{1}{2a}\le p(x)+q(x)\le\frac{1}{2a}\le \pi\tag{$\star$}$$
implying
$$-\pi\le k\pi\le \pi$$
from which $$ -1\le k\le 1$$
follows.

If $k=0$, then we get 
$$\begin{align}&\frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}+\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}=0
\\\\&\implies (a+2x)(5a^2-4ax+4x^2)+(2x-a)(5a^2+4ax+4x^2)=0
\\\\&\implies a(-8ax)+2x(10a^2+8x^2)=0
\\\\&\implies x(4x^2+3a^2)=0
\\\\&\implies x=0\end{align}$$

If $k=1$, then we have 
$$p(x)+q(x)=\pi$$
This is possible only when
$$p(x)+q(x)=\frac{1}{2a}=\pi$$
by $(\star)$.

From $(3)(4)$, we already have
$$p(x)\le\frac{1}{4a}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q(x)\le\frac{1}{4a}$$ 
Considering these, we see that $p(x)+q(x)=\frac{1}{2a}$ is possible only when $$p(x)=q(x)=\frac{1}{4a}\tag5$$ $p(x)=\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=\frac a2$ while $q(x)=\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=\frac 32a$. So, we see that $(5)$ is impossible.

If $k=-1$, we have to have $$p(x)=q(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}\tag6$$$p(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=-\frac 32a$ while $q(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=-\frac a2$. So, we see that $(6)$ is impossible.

Therefore, solving $(1)$ gives $x=0$ which is sufficient.

---

Next, let us solve $(2)$.

For $k\in\mathbb Z$,
$$(2)\implies p(x)-q(x)=k\pi$$
From $(3)(4)$, we have
$$-\pi \le -\frac{1}{2a}\le p(x)-q(x)\le\frac{1}{2a}\le \pi$$
from which $$-1\le k\le 1$$follows.

If $k=0$, then we have
$$\begin{align}&\frac{a+2 x}{5 a^2+4 a x+4 x^2}-\frac{2 x-a}{5 a^2-4 a x+4 x^2}=0
\\\\&\implies (a+2x)(5a^2-4ax+4x^2)-(2x-a)(5a^2+4ax+4x^2)=0
\\\\&\implies a(10a^2+8x^2)+2x(-8ax)=0
\\\\&\implies 4x^2-5a^2=0
\\\\&\implies x=\pm\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}a\end{align}$$

If $k=1$, we have to have $$p(x)=\frac{1}{4a}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}\tag7$$ $p(x)=\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=\frac a2$ while $q(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=-\frac a2$. So, we see that $(7)$ is impossible.

If $k=-1$, we have to have $$p(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q(x)=\frac{1}{4a}\tag8$$$p(x)=-\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=-\frac 32a$ while $q(x)=\frac{1}{4a}$ is attained only when $x=\frac 32a$. So, we see that $(8)$ is impossible.

Therefore, solving $(2)$ gives $x=\pm\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}a$ which are sufficient.

---

**Conclusion** :

$$\text{$x=0,\ \pm\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}a\ $ are the only solutions.}$$

Comment: Please base (5) in detail.

Comment: @user64494: I've added some explanations.